# WSO2 : Implementing Routing Slip Pattern using ESB

Tags: esb, wso2, wso2-esb

I used of 3 Header mediators for implementing Routing Slip pattern.  also used of Sequence structure as a Process unit of this pattern. i need to detect first slip (Header) in each Process (Sequence) after performing related process and rout the message to next Process unit based on this first slip and delete it from header soap. please guide me for this scenario.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can refer the documentation at http://docs.wso2.org/display/IntegrationPatterns/Routing+Slip 
You can use `iterate` and `switch` mediators to do the routing as mentioned in the doc.

Get value of soap header e.g. -

```
<property name="headerValue" expression="get-property('transport','Accept')"/>
```

Remove soap header e.g. -

```
<header name="ReplyTo" action="remove"/>
```

Comment: Dear Nufail, i've seen it befor, but my problem is another things. I said that i want to use only 1th value of Nth value that attached to soap header with same name (RoutingSlip). I dont know how can i read the first value and send message to it as a next processing step and remove it from header such that the remaining values of this header (RoutingSlip) still remain. if i remove RoutingSlip header all of its values would be removed!